# Can a Space exhibit both hyperbolic and spherical geometries

Tags: general-topology

From my understanding at least in 2 space the properties that differentiate spherical, hyperbolic, and euclidean space is lines and triangles.

Line property being that in spherical space two lines that are separated by a line perpendicular to both will eventually intersect. In euclidean space these lines will remain the same distance from each other. While in hyperbolic space these lines will diverge.

Similarly the angles of a triangle in spherical will add to greater then 180 degrees, exactly 180, and less then 180 in spherical, euclidean, and hyperbolic space respectively.

I was wondering if it's possible to construct a space that has properties of both hyperbolic and spherical spaces. Can this be done in 2 space or does it require aditional dimensions if so what n space is the minimum required to construct such a space?

Comment: A torus, maybe?

Comment: A generic Riemannian metric on a surface will have both positive and negative curvature on parts of a surface, hence, exhibiting both spherical and hyperbolic behavior.